# 32gb iso of linux live only 8gb used need to reduce to 16gb

Tags: windows

I have an Iso made from 32gb usb flash drive only 8gb used the rest is not allocated  I need to reduce the size of the iso to put it on a 16GB usb flash drive

Comment: It sounds like the ISO is actually an 8 GB ISO not a 32 GB ISO.  If that is the case then it should be able to be placed on a 16 GB storage device without a problem.

Comment: Format it NTFS so you can use files over 4GB on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well reducing the size of a file system is tricky. But the best *free* tool for the job under Linux is GParted. Use that from your flash drive to resize the partitions of your flash drive to the size you want. Then create a new ISO file from that.

BTW? 16gb... pretty sure no DVD-R can hold that much. Bluray holds 25gb or 50gb and HDDVD holds 15gb or 30gb. No optical media I'm familiar with holds 16gb of data. Not sure why your size restriction is 16gb for an optical disk image.

Comment: People often call any disk image "an iso" regardless of what medium it's meant for. I guess this started with the dual-use images made with isohybrid.

Comment: I see. Not seen that till now. It doesn't change my answer, but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If the rest is *really* unallocated (i.e. not covered by any filesystem or partition), truncate is the tool to use: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/truncate.1.html

Comment: It's worth noting that the second half of the filesystem being unallocated is exceedingly unlikely. Especially with the way the most common *nix filesystems (ext2/3/4fs in particular) work. They intentionally scatter files all over the disk in an attempt to prevent fragmentation. To be fair, flash media translates where the OS thinks the files are into contiguous space at the beginning of the flash memory anyway... but the OS can't "see" that and if you truncate where the OS thinks it's partitions/filesystems are it will still likely lead to data loss.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong that's why I said `really unallocated (i.e. not covered by any filesystem or partition)`. "Unused" doesn't mean it is "not covered / unallocated". The latter has nothing to do with whether the data are contiguous, but what the partition entries or the filesystem metadata (if partitionless) consider "owned".

Comment: Say on a disk image with a partition table, the size to use for truncate would be (ending LBA of last partition + 1) * logical block size.

Comment: Well, I dunno how to explain it, but I didn't see the part in parenthesis until now. So I apologize for the confusion. I can only suppose the association between "allocation" and "file allocation table" is what messed me up.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Heh no need to apologize. To be honest, I am not sure if there is standard definition for "unallocated" and "unused" in this context. It's just personally I would use the former for the "not covered/owned" sense and the latter as a synonym of free space in a filesystem.